# Tkinter not including in pyinstaller

Tags: python

Actually I'm trying to make a local search engine .The code works fine when running in pycharm but after created exe file using pyinstaller with options like `--hidden-import=Tkinter  --windowed`, while try to execute the exe file it shows  error like this

> D:\untitled\tk\dist\scroll>scroll.exe Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File "scroll.py", line 28, in  ImportError: No module
> named Tkinter
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "scroll.py", line 219, in
>  NameError: name 'Frame' is not defined Failed to execute
> script scroll
>
> D:\untitled\tk\dist\scroll>

The code written in python 2.7 is attached below I've also tried with python 3 but same problem

http://pastebin.com/4XWfcnzf